# Does Rails 6 finally provide a buit-in settings.yml feature like the old settingslogic gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

What (if any) method is the built-in "Rails 6 way" to including an environment-aware, ERB-aware, non-encypted method for storing app settings in the code? E.g., something just like the newer encrypted credentials, but without the obfuscating encryption.

For example, so you can have a file something like this:

```
# config/application.yml
defaults: &defaults
  cool:
    saweet: nested settings
  neat_setting: 24
  awesome_setting: <%= "Did you know 5 + 5 = #{5 + 5}?" %>

development:
  <<: *defaults
  neat_setting: 800

test:
  <<: *defaults

production:
  <<: *defaults
```

and fetch a (environment specific) setting something like this:
`Settings.neat_setting`

I've used the settingslogic gem for a decade, in many projects, but it isn't maintained so I hate to base a brand new Rails 6 app on it (even if it works ok today).

I find a lot of posts re Rails 3,4,5 but so far nothing new for Rails 6... and some of those same manual methods presumably work (make yml, make rb to load yml, figure out how to namespace the settings, etc) ... but surely by now Rails has some out-of-the-box (no 3rd party gem required) support for a simple app-specific .yml file?

Comment: https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-configurable/0.11/  I've used this, maybe it's worth exploring